# Slow insert & update into large table

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

So I have written a script which import data from a csv file with more than 1.5m rows into a mysql innodb table, it will scan the CSV, then for each CSV row:

- Search in the table to check if the record already exist.
- If exists, update the record.
- If not, insert new.

Then go to next row in CSV and do the above steps again.

The problem is, the table which data will be imported to also has 1.5m records, which make it too slow to import data. I tried the script and see that:

- If import data to an empty table, it can import 500 rows per minute.
- If import data to that 1.5m records table, it can only import 30 rows per minute.

Is there any solution to make the import progress faster?

Comment: Maybe replace the 3 steps with a single `insert into ... on duplicate key update ... ` . `INSERT` already does the duplicate key check making your own checking redundant.

Comment: can u show your table structure?

Comment: You need to give an example here, like `SHOW CREATE TABLE` that describes your table and associated indexes. As @apokryfos says, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is the real solution here, it does it all in one step, no mess. You can even insert directly from a CSV file.

Comment: For IODKU, you need a suitable `UNIQUE` index to determine when it is a 'duplicate'.

Comment: @apokryfos Please make your comment an actual answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is this:

You search the table for the key you're about to insert, however when you perform an insert the database management system will also perform integrity checks, i.e. ensure there's no `NULL` values on columns marked as `NOT NULL`, check if foreign key constraints are not violated, and (most important in this case), ensure primary keys and unique fields are unique.

This means that the DBMS will (among other things) search for the item when you perform the `INSERT` making your earlier search redundant.

You can replace the 3 operations with a single one which would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(column1,column2...) 
VALUES (v1,v2,....) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET column1=v1...
```

Also useful is to know that if you say `column1=VALUES(column1)` this means "use the value that I've specified in the `VALUES()` part of the insert.

Comment: Thank you! By using this solution, the import speed increased significantly from 30 orders/min to 4000 orders/min!

For more information, when a table is so large, if you use `SELECT WHERE` query, it will take a really long time to perform it (6 seconds) and that's the problem. I think the `Insert on duplicate key` thing will just insert the row without checking, and turn into an `update` query if a duplicate exception returned.